# Documenting javascript in Netbeans for autocompletion/code completion/intellisense

Tags: javascript, netbeans, autocomplete, intellisense

I am using Netbeans 6.9 and 7-Beta on Windows 7.  According to Netbeans [javascript documentation](http://netbeans.org/kb/65/ide/javascript-editor.html#code_completion) it should be possible to add documentation to my project and get autocompletion on my classes and functions.  The trouble I am having is that I'm using my own class declaration (via a function called `Class`) and can't seem to get things working.  For example a simple class declaration would look like:

```
mySubClass = Class(parentClass, {
  memberVariable: null,

  /**
   * @class mySubClass
   * @constructor
   */
  initialize: function(value) {
    this.memberVariable = value;
  },

  /**
   * @class mySubClass
   */
  getMV: function() {
    return this.memberVariable;
  },

  /**
   * @class mySubClass
   */  
  setMV: function(value) {
    this.memberVariable = value;
  }
});
```

I've tried many variations and placements of the declarations (`@class`, `@memberOf`, etc) but cannot get completion working.  For example after,

```
var testObj = new my
```

I should be able to get `mySubClass` by hitting "ctrl+space" and similarly proceed to:

```
var test = new mySubClass(1);
test.
```

and get options for `getMV` and `setMV`.  Is this possible and if so, how do I do it?  Thanks.

Comment: Since all I care about is code completion I'm working on a script to convert my basic javascript into a form that netbeans will read correctly.  I'll report back later if I get it working.

Comment: Did you ever sort this out? I also am looking for a way to get netbeans to provide code completion on class definitions similar to yours.

Comment: @Tristan: I have not found a solution yet.  I looked at coding a plugin to do this, but it's way more complex than I have time for.  Is there any way to close a question that has no answer?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Your code could have been simplified, I had to read twice to understand that Class was a custom function of yours, not js syntax..

```
foo.canvas = function(id) {
  this.clear = function() {};
};
bar = foo.canvas("myCanvas");
bar. <-- here NetBeans doesn't suggest the "clear" function.
```

It seems the NetBeans doesn't do introspection well in JS. It only seems to work for *native* and *host* objects.

Try Komodo Edit, it seems to get this right.

Comment: Thanks for looking at the problem.  I'm reluctant to learn a whole new editor to fix this one problem, especially since its not clear it will work with my `Class` function as originally mentioned.  I'm beginning to think the current verions (6.9 and 7beta) will not do what I need them to do.  I have one hack of a solution in the works (more later) and am hoping they will add more detailed jsdoc support soon.

Answer (score 0):

It **should** work with @lends (see [JSDoc-toolkit CookBook](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/CookBook#Sub-class_Pattern)). It doesn't work in Netbeans 7.2 though (even @type and @link doesn't work).